# Panning AudioKit's AKMetronome

Tags: xcode, audiokit

I am making a metronome app and I need to pan one metronome to the left and another to the right. I know AKMetronome class has no pan property, but can anyone suggest I can accomplish this?

```
 let mixer = AKMixer(metronome, metronome2)

 AudioKit.output = mixer
 try AudioKit.start()
 metronome.start()
 metronome2.start()
```

Above code works but two metronomes are both centered. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AKPanner will do the trick:

https://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKPanner.html

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/master/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Mixing/Panner/AKPanner.swift

```
let leftPan = AKPanner(metronome)
leftPan.pan = -1

let rightPan = AKPanner(metronome2)
rightPan.pan = 1

let mixer = AKMixer(leftPan, rightPan)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it!